# Creating a number string from list of numbers in scheme

Tags: string, list, numbers, scheme, racket

So I've just figured out that you can use string->number to convert string `365` into int `365`. But now I have another question:

How do I take, for example, `(1 2 3)`, and convert it to string `123` so I can apply `string->number` to it? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

If it helps: I am using drracket 6.0

Comment: You should not have deleted your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23006630/13), if that were the actual problem you were trying to solve. Because now, you've turned this question into an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/13).

Comment: (For non-10k users: the original question was about how to turn a list like `'(123 45 6)` into the number 123456.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer your [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23006630/13), not your current one, which is just one possible solution approach.

There are a number of ways to solve this. One way, like you mentioned in this question, is to convert the incoming list of numbers into strings, then concatenating them:

```
(require srfi/13)
(define (number-concatenate nums)
  (string->number (string-concatenate (map number->string nums))))
```

Here's another approach, that does not involve conversion to strings first:

```
(require srfi/1 srfi/26)
(define (number-concatenate nums)
  (define (expand num)
    (if (< num 10)
        (list num)
        (unfold-right zero? (cut modulo <> 10) (cut quotient <> 10) num)))

  (fold (lambda (num result)
          (fold (lambda (digit result)
                  (+ digit (* result 10)))
                result (expand num)))
        0 nums))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have array of numbers you can do like this(javascript code)-

```
 [1,2,3].join('');
    o/p=>"123"
```